# Reversed stack returns one item

Tags: java, reference, linked-list, stack, reverse

I have a generic LinkedStack class with a LinkedStack reversed method
It creates a new LinkedStack say newLinkedstack and pushes items from the current stack by popping them. So at the end of the operation the current stack is left empty and newLinkedStack contains the same items/elements that were in "this" stack only in reverse order.

My code compiles but when I create and fill up a stack and then print out the contents, 
I only get one result.

```
public LinkedStack<T> rev()
{
LinkedStack<T> revStack=new LinkedStack<T>();
//final int SIZE=this.size();    
while(!(this.empty)){//for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
{
  revStack.push(this.pop());
 } 
return revStack;
}
```

For example

```
LinkedStack<String> newLS = new LinkedStack<String>();
newLS.push("noid");
newLS.push("enilec");
newLS.push("River");
newLS.push("Healing");
newLS.push("Pain");
```

and `newLS.rev()` returns `Pain` instead of a reversed stack

**UPDATE**

Here's my pop method

```
public T pop()
{
    T element=peek();
    top=top.next;
    return element;
}
```

I have two push methods this one moves every element from input stack to current stack leaving input stack from argument empty

```
  public void push(LinkedStack<T> stack){ 
    //int SZE = stack.size();
    while(!(stack.empty())){//formally for(int i=0;i<SZE;i++){
        this.push(stack.pop());}}
```

Here's my other push method

```
public void push(T element)
{
   top=new Node<T>(item,top);
}
```

Comment: You have to show the implementation of push and pop. And other methods if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where LinkedStack came from, but it seems that the bug is being caused by that class's implementation.

You'll have to post more source code if you want more specific help.